# How to position a beamer box in a slide?

Tags: beamer, positioning

How can I position a `beamercolorbox` in arbitrary position in a slide?

I want to be able to give coordinates, and that is where the box will be positioned.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't know how to do that directly. But, whenever i want to put stuff in strange places in my slides, i use the `textpos` package. If you are going to use it with beamer, i hear it is advisable to use the overlay option. I also find it easier to use absolute references to place things (distances measured from the top left corner of the slide). To do both you should use

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
```

To place things in the slides use

```
\begin{textblock*}{width}(xcoord,ycoord)
whatever you want to put here
\end{textblock*}
```

One drawback of this solution is that you have to manually specify the width...

Not directly related to the question, but when using this i find it useful to have a grid on the slides. You can add one by using

```
\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=red!10,subgridcolor=green!10]
{eso-pic}
```

Comment: Thanks a million from the future, especially for the grid!

Comment: Where can I find more information about the `textblock*` environment? Why the `*`?

Comment: You can find more information in the textpos package manual. From the manual: "In the argument to the {textblock* } environment, the block width, and the block position (but not the specification of the block reference point) are given as absolute dimensions, rather than as numbers in units of the horizontal and vertical modules."